# Partition a table by date

Tags: hadoop, hive, partition

Running Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.4.0-91.  I have a table with 1 trillion records that need to run the following - I need to create partitions by date (one partition per day). Did anyone do this?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Please add some more information and possibly code.

Comment: I am trying to partition a large table into multiple tables using date as the criteria

Comment: when we do partion by date process is crashing

Comment: Edit your post and post some code and the error risen there, specialists in Hive may help you find your problem.